# how to map array of strings while assigning priorities

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to map some strings to numbers which are used to priorities each one of them, the following way works fine but I don't think its the best way to do it.

any suggestions on how to write this piece of code in a better way ?

```js
  private readonly PRIORITY: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>([
        ['XDR', 1],
        ['PT1M', 2],
        ['PT1M_', 2],
        ['PT5M', 3],
        ['PT5M_', 3],
        ['PT15M', 4],
        ['PT15M_', 4],
        ['PT1H', 5],
        ['PT1H_', 5],
        ['P1D', 6],
        ['P1D_', 6],
        ['P7D', 7],
        ['P1W', 7],
        ['P1M', 8]
    ]);
    private  getsAsPriorityMap(): Map<string, number> {
        const result: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();
        const Widgets = ViewManager.getView().getWidgets();
        Widgets.forEach(graphWidget => {
            const gran = QueryProcessorService.getWidgetApplied(Widget);
            if (gran) {
                result.set(gran, this.PRIORITY.get(gran));
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
```

the way the array looks is confusing I want to write in a way in which it would be easily readable by anyone reading my code

Comment: What about it looks "confusing"? The only things I would do on first look is get rid of the `debugger` statement and put that constant on top of the file (if it isn't already there), or separate constants into a separate file and import them.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use an enum, or am I missing something in the question?

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu can you show me how to in this example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an enum it should look like this:

```
enum PRIORITY {
  XDR = 1,
  PT1M = 2,
  PT1M_ = 2,
  PT5M = 3,
  PT5M_ = 3,
  PT15M = 4,
  PT15M_ = 4,
  PT1H = 5,
  PT1H_ = 5,
  P1D = 6,
  P1D_ = 6,
  P7D = 7,
  P1W = 7,
  P1M = 8,
}
```

And your getter would look something similar to the following:

```
 private getsAsPriorityMap(): string[][] {
    const widgets = ViewManager.getView().getWidgets();
    return widgets.reduce((acc, curWidget) => {
      const gran = QueryProcessorService.getWidgetApplied(curWidget);
      acc.push([gran.toString(), PRIORITY[gran].toString()]);
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
```

Comment: If you clarify what kind of an output you would like to see, I can try to modify your getter too.

Comment: it would be great if you could help me with the getter too , it will return an array or type: Map<string, number> .
ex :
[
        ['XDR', 1],
        ['PT1M', 2],
        ['PT1M_', 2],]

Comment: Can you explain me the Widget logic as well, or should I exclude those parts from the method?

Comment: the widgets returns one of those symbols XDR and each has a different priorities , so I return an array of all what the widgets return and map them with priority numbers

Comment: it doesn't return an array though

Comment: Ok mb, for some reason I thought it would be more reasonable to return an object, I have updated my original answer to suit your use case.